# php and Content-Length header connection stall

Tags: php, http, header, content-length

I have a php website. Since I'm using template engine and I always do the html in "one-shot" I have the size of the html document upfront. So I decided to set Content-Length header for better performance. If I don't set it the document is transferred using chunked encoding.

The php code for html output looks like this:

```
header('Accept-Ranges: none');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));

echo $content;
```

I tested it under windows in Chrome, IE, Firefox and Safari - it works file. However Microsoft Bing bot (using bing webmaster tools) said that the website does not respond. I decided to investigate and here is what I found out:

- wget works fine on CentOS 5.x and CentOS 6.x
- elinks on CentOS 6.x works fine
- elinks on CentOS 5.x **stalls** (version elinks-0.11.1-6.el5_4.1)

so elinks on Centos 5 was the only http client that I found which has problems accessing the site. However I don't know how to get debug information out of it.

Questions:

1. Can someone tell me how to get debug info out of elinks. Is it possible to have raw dup of http+headers? Or some kind of error log
2. Any idea why stalling happens in one client and doesn't heppen in another?
3. Well it's most probably the incorrect header "Content-Length" that's causing the problem because when I remove it it works fine in elinks and Bing. What could cause content lenght difference
4. Any other http clients to test with?

All tests are done on the same web server, the same php version, the same web page and with the same content. What I can think of is UTF-8 text file identifier (the few bytes in front of a text file that some browsers place)

Here is a dump of headers with wget:

```
wget dev.site.com/ --server-response -O /dev/null
--2013-11-09 01:32:37--  http://dev.site.com/
Resolving dev.site.com... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to dev.site.com|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 23:32:37 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Set-Cookie: lng=en; expires=Wed, 07-May-2014 23:32:37 GMT; path=/; domain=dev.site.com
  Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 23:32:37 GMT
  Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
  Pragma: no-cache
  Expires: 0
  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=8a1e9b871474b882e1eef4ca0dfea0fc; expires=Thu, 06-Feb-2014 23:32:37 GMT; path=/
  Content-Language: en
  Set-Cookie: hc=1518952; expires=Mon, 17-Nov-2036 00:38:00 GMT; path=/; domain=dev.site.com
  Accept-Ranges: none
  Content-Length: 16970
  Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Length: 16970 (17K) [text/html]
Saving to: “/dev/null”

100%[===================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 16,970      --.-K/s   in 0.1s

2013-11-09 01:32:37 (152 KB/s) - “/dev/null” saved [16970/16970]
```

**update:**

I was able to reproduce the problem, but only on production server. One difference I notice between the working and non-working elinks is that non-working sends this header:
    Accept-Encoding: gzip

Of course if it's gzipped the size will be different. zlib.output_compression is On on php.ini. I guess that could be the problem. Also output buffering is 4096. That's strange because most browsers use compression when available. I'll try again in a web browser.

Yes browser (chrome) also asks for compression and gzip exists in response headers:

```
Content-Length: 15916
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

view source shows exactly 15916 bytes. Chrome has an option to show raw headers as well as parsed. What could be happening is that Chrome actually decompresses data before counting. Sounds strange but it's the only explanation why GUI web browsers work and some lower level clients don't

Comment: Is the variable data that is included in the template always the same size to where you 100% know for sure what the content length is, or are you loading everything into an output buffer and measuring the size?

Comment: have you tried wireshark to investigate (when using elinks)?

Comment: @MikeBrant well, The size doesn't change when I try to download the same page again. tried with curl - still the same. And no, I'm not using output buffer (i.e. ob_start). So if something else writes it'll make the size of document different than content-length. However that's not very likely to behave different in different browsers. I don't have any code checking the user agent or anything related to the browser.

Comment: @hek2mgl I could use tcpdump ... I didn't think about that. But Murphy gets you every time - I can't repeat the problem. It just loaded with elinks on centos 5.x I'll keep trying. I had the same problem with other sites where i simply load a file, set header with size and print it to output without changes and it had the same effect - some clients work, other don't

Comment: @NickSoft From my experience, mostly DNS outages are the cause of such things. But that's just an assumption of course. Let me know if you know more.. (like that network miracles)

Comment: @hek2mgl most probably not DNS as it's fixed immediately after I remove Content-Length header. But ... Murphy .. I've put Content-Length header back and now I can't reproduce the problem. I did that few times before but it wasn't fixed. If I'll try to capture and post some sniff dumps.

Comment: are you testing with always (exactly) the same http response (headers + body)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is already there. `Content-Length` has to be the size that is actually being sent, which is the size *after* the '$content' is compressed. The size of the content you see on view-source is naturally decompressed size.

Connection does not stall. Your browser is waiting for more data to come but compressed data size is smaller than what browser is waiting for. If your server eventually timeouts the connection your browser will assume it got all the data and show it. It works with wget and such because they don't send accept-compression headers and server does not send compressed response.

If you must, you could disable compressing, manually compress and send `$content` and also appropriate `Content-Encoding` headers.

Another option is to download the page uncompressed (send `Accept-Encoding: gzip` with wget, I guess it won't get decompressed, but even though it is not enabled by default wget might support compression after all, I don't know. I know cURL doesn't support it you can use it) and get the size of the response minus headers (which means only size of the data *after* `\r\n\r\n` header end sequence) and use that size while sending `Content-Length`. But of course changing compression level or maybe implementation (different web servers/modules or different versions of the same web server/modules) will change the size of the resulting compressed data so this is a very fragile way to do this.

Why are you modifying `Content-Length` anyway? Php or web server is supposed to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no nice-and-clean solution. I would love to be able to set zlib buffer size with:

```
zlib.output_compression = 131072
```

if I'm sure the page won't be more than 128k (uncompressed), however there is no way to get compressed size of the buffer.

**So there are two solutions:**

1. turn off output compression or do not set Content-Length ... which is not much of a solution, but it works
2. replace zlib compression handler with:

---

```
ob_start(); // start normal buffer
ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); // start gzip buffer
echo $content;
ob_end_flush(); // output gzipped content

$gzippedContent = ob_get_contents(); // store gzipped content to get size
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($gzippedContent));
ob_end_flush(); // flush gzipped content
```

But make sure that zlib.output_compression is Off.

Even though php manual sais that zlib.output_compression is prefered I doubt that using ob_gzhandler will dramatically reduce the performance.

You can set compression level by

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', 4);
```

I tested it and it works with both gzip enabled in client/browser and with gzip disabled.

```
wget --header='Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' -O ./page.html.gz http://www.site.com/ && gunzip page.html.gz
wget -O ./page.html http://www.site.com/
```

Comment: I meant a custom php script to compress. I didn't know you could get the compressed buffer with  `ob_` functions, it will do well.

Comment: On http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php comments there is an example of using gzcompress, but I had troubles accessing raw request headers before. I think it's only possible in some cases (depending if it's apache module, cgi or if the server is different - IIS or other). So I can't always access "Accept-Encoding" request header. Compression with php scrit is not an option. The whole idea is to optimize performance not to make it worse.

Comment: Why are you trying to explicitly set `Content-Length`. Doesn't web server or PHP set it for you already after the compression? I did some simple things with PHP/Apache/Nginx but did not need to adjust `Content-Length` manually, whether compressed or not.

Comment: Apache can not set content length because it doesn't know it. To do so the whole page must be buffered. The page isn't big, but Apache can't know that upfront. That's why it can't set size. I know when the page isn't going to be big, so I can buffer it and set the content length. The performance should be little bit better compared to chunked transfer.

Comment: Ah so it sends it `chunked` to avoid buffering, I didn't know it. Anyway the problem was sending wrong `Content-Length` you may want to mark an answer mine or yours.

Comment: Well yors didn't have complete solution and I kinda said it when updated the question, but I'll mark your answer for the efforts. My answer is to provide useful information for people that have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem -- I was trying set the `Content-Length` header without being realizing that the length I measured inside the buffer would be larger than the actual GZip'd output (and yes, it seemed like the browser was hung).  I stumbled upon this Q&A after I'd already solved my problem (solution below).

@Etherealone is spot-on with one point:

> Connection does not stall. Your browser is waiting for more data to come but compressed data size is smaller than what browser is waiting for.

@Etherealone and @NickSoft both kinda hinted at this, but didn't actually say it: a `Content-Length` header for dynamically-generated content isn't necessary, and the server should instead send a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.  This tells the browser to keep the connection open until it receives a zero-length chunk, which signifies the end of the content.

However, chunking the transfer does add a bit of overhead, so wanting to specify a `Content-Length` certainly doesn't hurt.  @NickSoft had the right idea, but it doesn't have to be quite so complicated.

So, if you insist on having a `Content-Length` header instead of letting the server chunk the content, then all you have to do is just buffer twice; once for compression, then again so you can measure the size and send the `Content-Length` header:

```
<?php

// "Outer" buffer to capture content and size of "inner" buffer and send content length header
ob_start();

// "Inner" buffer for compression
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

// Do stuff...
echo $content;

// Flush the inner buffer, the contents of which is GZip'd
ob_end_flush();

// Measure the inner buffer size and set the header
header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());  

// Send the outer buffer
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

After I implemented this, I saw the new `Content-Length` header; the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header disappeared; and the "hung" browser symptom went away (the browser got all of the content and closed the connection).